# Powershell convert csv from rows to columns

Tags: excel, powershell

Would anyone know of a way to convert multiple rows in a csv to columns, using powershell?

I have no idea why the customer wants it in this format

Thanks

Input:

```
VmName    ResourceGroupName Region     VmSize         VirturalNetwork Subnet  DnsServers NicDns PrivateIpAddress  OsType OSDisk DiagDisk DataDisk PublicIPAddress vCPU Memory
------    ----------------- ------     ------         --------------- ------  ---------- ------ ----------------  ------ ------ -------- -------- --------------- ---- ------
vmr1-sec1 DEPLOYRG1         westeurope Standard_D2_v4 av-vnet         av-sub2                   172.0.2.4        Windows                                             2   8192
vmr2-sec1 DEPLOYRG1         westeurope Standard_D2_v4 av-vnet         av-sub2                   172.0.2.5        Windows                                             2   8192
cks-cp1   K8S               westeurope Standard_B2s   K8S-vnet        default                   10.0.0.4           Linux                          20.71.120.71       2   4096
```

Comment: Do you have any sample input/output?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hi Thanks for the quick response, I've added the input data.

Comment: And the output format? Do you want to retain the column headers as the first column when pivoting?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, I was thinking first column would be headers and the other columns data values, if that makes sense

Comment: Ask your customer what happens on those columns where there is no value, how will he know what they're referring to

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon can we not leave that cell empty, so it would be column A with headers and the other columns would list the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$object = @'
VmName,ResourceGroupName,Region,VmSize,VirturalNetwork,Subnet,DnsServers,NicDns,PrivateIpAddress,OsType,OSDisk,DiagDisk,DataDisk,PublicIPAddress,vCPU,Memory
vmr1-sec1,DEPLOYRG1,westeurope,Standard_D2_v4,av-vnet,av-sub2,,,172.0.2.4,Windows,,,,,2,8192
vmr2-sec1,DEPLOYRG1,westeurope,Standard_D2_v4,av-vnet,av-sub2,,,172.0.2.5,Windows,,,,,2,8192
cks-cp1,K8S,westeurope,Standard_B2s,K8S-vnet,default,,,10.0.0.4,Linux,,,,20.71.120.71,2,4096
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$props = $object[0].psobject.Properties.Name
$newObj = [collections.generic.list[string]]::new()

foreach($prop in $props)
{
    $column = $object.$prop
    
    $newLine = foreach($item in $column)
    {
        if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item))
        {
            '-'
        }
        else
        {
            $item
        }
    }
    
    $newObj.Add("$prop,$($newLine -join ',')")
}
```

Result:

```
PS /> $newObj | ConvertFrom-Csv

VmName            vmr1-sec1      vmr2-sec1      cks-cp1     
------            ---------      ---------      -------     
ResourceGroupName DEPLOYRG1      DEPLOYRG1      K8S         
Region            westeurope     westeurope     westeurope  
VmSize            Standard_D2_v4 Standard_D2_v4 Standard_B2s
VirturalNetwork   av-vnet        av-vnet        K8S-vnet    
Subnet            av-sub2        av-sub2        default     
DnsServers        -              -              -           
NicDns            -              -              -           
PrivateIpAddress  172.0.2.4      172.0.2.5      10.0.0.4    
OsType            Windows        Windows        Linux       
OSDisk            -              -              -           
DiagDisk          -              -              -           
DataDisk          -              -              -           
PublicIPAddress   -              -              20.71.120.71
vCPU              2              2              2           
Memory            8192           8192           4096
```

Worth mentioning that if more than **one** `VmName` is missing `ConvertFrom-Csv` will throw this error:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv : The member "-" is already present.
At line:1 char:9
+ $newObj|convertfrom-csv
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromCsvCommand
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could I ask, how did yo get the object properties, did you save the csv as text file and import teh data?

Comment: @NorrinRad Properties are coming from this `$props = $object[0].psobject.Properties.Name`. That will work with any object.